How to get array length of int*?
I want to know how to calculate the array length of int*. I know that the length of int arr[] is obtained by using sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), but how to get the length of an int* array?
Below is my code.
int Summation( int* nums ){
    int size = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]);
    return size;
}

int firstSum = Summation( first ); // first is an array of int*

Input
789

My output
2


You cannot. C/C++ decay array to a plain pointer when you pass in the array to another function. There is no way to know the size except to pass it as an extra parameter.

nums is a pointer, not an array; sizeof nums == sizeof (int *), not sizeof (int [N]) (for whatever N you used for first).  Arrays lose their "array-ness" under most circumstances, including when passed as function arguments.  You'll have to pass the array size as a separate parameter.

@TanveerBadar Clear my doubts. Thank you !
